Is there precedent to the IOC 'derecognizing' IBA?
Last year the IOC 'derecognized' the International Boxing Association (IBA). Is this the first time the IOC has done something like this? (The AP story doesn't mention any precedents.)

IBA is the first, and so far only, international governing body to have recognition withdrawn by the IOC.
Several articles reporting on the event mention this fact, such as InsideTheGames.biz:

The IBA became the first-ever International Federation to be removed from the Olympic Movement by the IOC, having been suspended since 2019 for issues with finances, governance and the credibility of boxing competitions.

